# How to use Kotlin's Ktorm to perform WHERE clause operation on custom Postgres "object type" avoiding "PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, orm, operation, kotlin-dsl

Whilst performing a WHERE clause operation on a custom Postgres "object type" I ended up the following PSQLException.

- **Language**: Kotlin.
- **ORM Library**: [Ktorm ORM](https://www.ktorm.org/).

**Exception**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: rate = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have followed the [Ktorm official guides here](https://www.ktorm.org/en/entities-and-column-binding.html) but, there is no mention of custom Postgres types.  Any pointers/help would be highly appreciated. See code below to reproduce:

Thank you.

1. Example test that would produce the above exception

```kotlin
internal class SuppliersInstanceDAOTest {


    @Test
    fun shouldReturnInstanceSequence() {

        val database = Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb", user = "postgres", password = "superpassword")

        val instanceDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 1)
        database.withSchemaTransaction("suppliers") {
            database.from(SuppliersInstanceTable)
                .select(SuppliersInstanceTable.instanceSeq)
                .whereWithConditions {
                // The following line causes "ERROR: operator does not exist: rate = character varying"
                    it += SuppliersInstanceTable.rate eq Rate.DAILY
                }.asIterable()
                .first()
                .getInt(1)
        }
        
    }
}
```

1. Schema

```sql
-- Note the special custom enum object type here that I cannot do anything about
CREATE TYPE suppliers.rate AS ENUM
    ('Daily', 'Byweekly');

CREATE TABLE suppliers.instance
(
    rate suppliers.rate NOT NULL,
    instance_value integer NOT NULL
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

3. Kotlin's Ktorms Entities and bindings

```kotlin
enum class Rate(val value: String) {
    DAILY("Daily"),
    BIWEEKLY("Byweekly")
}

interface SuppliersInstance : Entity<SuppliersInstance> {
    companion object : Entity.Factory<SuppliersInstance>()
    val rate: Rate
    val instanceSeq: Int
}

object SuppliersInstanceTable : Table<SuppliersInstance>("instance") {
    val rate = enum("rate", typeRef<Rate>()).primaryKey().bindTo { it.rate } // <-- Suspect
    //val rate = enum<Rate>("rate", typeRef()).primaryKey().bindTo { it.rate } // Failed too

    val instanceSeq = int("instance_value").primaryKey().bindTo { it.instanceSeq }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeking help from the maintainers of Ktorm, it turns out there is support in the newer version of ktorm for native Postgressql enum object types.  In my case I needed `pgEnum` instead of the default ktrom `enum` function that converts the enums to varchar causing the clash in types in Postressql:

[Reference here for pgEnum](https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/blob/master/ktorm-support-postgresql/src/main/kotlin/org/ktorm/support/postgresql/SqlTypes.kt#L84-L110)

However, note at the time of writing ktorm's pgEnum function is only in ktorm v3.2.x +.  The latest version available in [Jcentral](https://jcenter.bintray.com/me/liuwj/ktorm/ktorm-support-postgresql/) and [mavenCentral](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/me/liuwj/ktorm/ktorm-support-postgresql/) maven repositories is v3.1.0.  This is because there is also a group name change from `me.liuwj.ktorm` to `org.ktorm` in the latest version. So upgrading would also mean changing the group name in your dependencies for the new group name to match the maven repos.  This was a seamless upgrade for my project and the new pgEnum worked in my use case.

For my code examples above, this would mean swapping this

```kotlin
object SuppliersInstanceTable : Table<SuppliersInstance>("instance") {
    val rate = enum("rate", typeRef<Rate>()).primaryKey().bindTo { it.rate } <---
    ...
}
```

For

```kotlin
object SuppliersInstanceTable : Table<SuppliersInstance>("instance") {
    val rate = pgEnum<Rate>("rate").primaryKey().bindTo { it.rate } <---
    ...
}
```